# How to create a spreadsheet with j2me or j2mePolish?

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

I want to create a spreadsheet like Microsoft Excel with j2me or j2mePolish. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this project, [Simple spreadsheet for j2me.](http://code.google.com/p/simple-spreadsheet/) Just checkout that project source code and do it.

Comment: there are errors in the source code : the Classes Table, RecordsForm are unknown ! Where to find them ?

Comment: I copied the code from this link : http://code.google.com/p/simple-spreadsheet/source/browse/trunk/src/SpreadSheet.java# . So when I paste it in the WTK then it does not recognize the two classes I mentioned !

Comment: No. If have SVN, just checkout that project and use it or copy [all classes from src path](http://code.google.com/p/simple-spreadsheet/source/browse/trunk/src/) and use it.

Comment: ah ! ok then ! So I must get all the files !

Comment: how to coloriate even rows and odd rows differently with these code ?

Comment: Dont have any idea. Because i didnt use this before. Look at table class and paint method. That should be possible on this method.